# Почему не увеливается цифра в колонке?

Tags: python, mysql, telegram, aiogram

Подскажите, пожалуйста, при добавлении, 2 свои аккаунтов, в группу телеграм, всё равно, цифра 1, в колонке new_chat_members.
Мне нужно, сделать так, если пользователь, не пригласит, 40 контактов, в группу, не сможет, писать в группе. На одном сайте, мне написали так, цитирую "Обработчик кнопки, внутри проверка."

Это, фото, одного бота, как я, пытаюсь, сделать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фото Бд.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Бд код.

```
connection = sqlite3.connect("new_chat_members.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()
connection.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS
        (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, user_id INTEGER, chat_id INTEGER, name TEXT, username TEXT, new_chat_members INTEGER)''')
connection.commit()

class SQLither:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def add_user(self, user_id, chat_id, name, username, new_chat_members):
            with self.connection:
                return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' (user_id, chat_id, name, username, new_chat_members) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)", (user_id, chat_id, name, username, new_chat_members))

    def user_exists(self, user_id, chat_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=? and chat_id=?", (user_id,chat_id,)).fetchall()

db = SQLither("new_chat_members.db")
```

Хендлер, при отправке сообщения, удаляет и устанавливает ограничения.

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'photo', 'video', 'document', 'audio', 'video_note', 'voice', 'animation', 'contact', 'dice', 'location', 'poll', 'sticker', 'venue'])
async def get_handler(message: types.Message):      
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    username = message.from_user.username
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    first_name = message.from_user.first_name
    last_name = message.from_user.last_name
    name = message.from_user.full_name


    ChatMember.status = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=message.from_user.id)
    ChatMemberUpdated.new_chat_member = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=message.from_user.id)
    #print(ChatMemberUpdated)
    if not ChatMember.status in ChatMemberUpdated.new_chat_member.user:
                keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
                checkurl = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='✅Я добавил(а) контакты', callback_data=f'captcha_member:{user_id}')
                keyboard.add(checkurl)
                try:
                    msg = await message.reply(f"Извините! <a href=\"tg://user?id={user_id}\">{name}</a>. \n<b> Вам нужно добавить, 40 человек, прежде чем, Вы сможете, публиковать сообщения, в группе.</b>".format(message.from_user.id), disable_web_page_preview=True, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=keyboard)
                    asyncio.create_task(delete_message(msg, 180))
                    await message.delete()
                    await asyncio.sleep(2)
                    await bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id, ChatPermissions(can_send_messages=False, can_send_media_messages=False, can_send_other_messages=False, can_add_web_page_previews=False, can_send_polls=False, can_pin_messages=False, can_invite_users=True))
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    return
```

Обработчик кнопки, но при добавлении контактов, не, снимает ограничения.

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith='captcha')
#@dp.callback_query_handler(text="captcha")
async def captcha_member(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    user_id = str(call.from_user.id)
    to_id = call.data.split(':')[1]
    chat_id = call.message.chat.id
    username = call.from_user.username
    name = call.from_user.full_name
    new_chat_members = len(call.message.new_chat_members)

    ChatMemberMember.status = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, user_id=call.from_user.id)
    ChatMemberUpdated.new_chat_member = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, user_id=call.from_user.id)
    if ChatMemberUpdated.new_chat_member in ChatMemberMember.status and user_id in to_id:
        await bot.restrict_chat_member(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, user_id=call.from_user.id, permissions=types.ChatPermissions(can_send_messages=True, can_send_media_messages=True, can_send_other_messages=True, can_add_web_page_previews=True, can_send_polls=True, can_pin_messages=True, can_invite_users=True, can_change_info=True, until_date=None))
        if db.user_exists(user_id, chat_id):
            db.add_to_db(call.from_user.id, chat_id, name, username, new_chat_members)

    elif user_id in to_id:
        await call.answer(text="Вы пригласили, меньше 40 или ни кого, не пригласили.", show_alert=True)

    else:
        await call.answer(text="Эта ссылка адресована другому пользователю", show_alert=True)
```

Этот, хендлер, считывает кто пригласил в группу, или сам присоединился, к группе.

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
async def new_user_joined(message: types.Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    username = message.from_user.username
    name = message.from_user.full_name
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    new_chat_members = len(message.new_chat_members)

    ChatMemberMember = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=message.from_user.id)
    ChatMemberUpdated.new_chat_member = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=message.from_user.id)

    if ChatMemberUpdated.new_chat_member:
        if not db.user_exists(user_id, chat_id):
                    db.add_user(message.from_user.id, chat_id, name, username, new_chat_members)
                    return
```

Подскажите, как прописать, чтобы работало, долго, делаю, свой код, плохо, понимаю пайтов, всё, методом экспериментов и чтения документации, просмотров видео уроков, о пайтоне.

Фото.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из того, как я понял ваш вопрос - вам нужно обновить значение `new_chat_member` в БД при приглашении пользователем человека. Для обновления значений в уже существующей записи используйте `UPDATE`.
Вот пример кода, который может вам помочь:

```
def user_added_new_user(self, user_id):
     with self.connection:
          self.cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET new_chat_members = new_chat_members + 1 WHERE user_id=?", (user_id,))
```

Вставьте его в код БД и вызывайте его в файле `main` внутри метода `new_user_joined`

```
db.user_added_new_user(user_id)
```

После вызова, значение `new_chat_member` в БД станет на 1 больше (т.е. было 1, станет 2), у переданного методу пользователя

Comment: Спасибо, подскажите пожалуйста, а как в main прописать.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, ошибку пишет TypeError: user_added_new_user() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Судя по тому, что вы написали - вы передали методу 2 переменные, вместо одной.

Comment: в пачарме эта строка def user_added_new_user(user_id):  user_id не горить и 2 self. волнистой красного цвета, может поэтому ошибка.
Прикрепил фото, посмотрите.

Comment: Дополнил ответ, нужно добавить `self` в `def`.

Comment: Благодарю, всё заработало, добавил 2 контакта и цифра 2 написана.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как прописать, чтобы, например минимум 20 контактов пригласить и нажать, на кнопку, чтобы ограничения снялись и пользователь, смог писать в группе.

Comment: Создайте новый вопрос и пришлите ссылку сюда. Если моё решение вам помогло - пометьте его как ответ. Спасибо

Comment: Создал https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1533991/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8