# Как сделать, Обработчик кнопки?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, callback

Подскажите пожалуйста, нужно сделать, обработчик кнопки, чтобы, снять ограничения в группе, например, если минимум 20 контактов, пригласил, в группу.

Хендлер, при отправке сообщения, удаляет и устанавливает ограничения.

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'photo', 'video', 'document', 'audio', 'video_note', 'voice', 'animation', 'contact', 'dice', 'location', 'poll', 'sticker', 'venue'])
async def get_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):       
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    username = message.from_user.username
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    first_name = message.from_user.first_name
    last_name = message.from_user.last_name
    name = message.from_user.full_name


    ChatMember.status = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=message.from_user.id)
    ChatMemberUpdated.new_chat_member = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=message.from_user.id)
    #print(ChatMemberUpdated)
    if not ChatMember.status in ChatMemberUpdated.new_chat_member.user:
                keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
                checkurl = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='✅Я добавил(а) контакты', callback_data=f'captcha_member:{user_id}')
                keyboard.add(checkurl)
                try:
                    msg = await message.reply(f"Извините! <a href=\"tg://user?id={user_id}\">{name}</a>. \n<b> Вам нужно добавить, 40 человек, прежде чем, Вы сможете, публиковать сообщения, в группе.</b>".format(message.from_user.id), disable_web_page_preview=True, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=keyboard)
                    asyncio.create_task(delete_message(msg, 180))
                    await message.delete()
                    await asyncio.sleep(2)
                    await bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id, ChatPermissions(can_send_messages=False, can_send_media_messages=False, can_send_other_messages=False, can_add_web_page_previews=False, can_send_polls=False, can_pin_messages=False, can_invite_users=True))
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    return
```

Обработчик кнопки, но при добавлении контактов, не, снимает ограничения.

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith='captcha')
#@dp.callback_query_handler(text="captcha")
async def captcha_member(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    user_id = str(call.from_user.id)
    to_id = call.data.split(':')[1]
    chat_id = call.message.chat.id
    username = call.from_user.username
    name = call.from_user.full_name
    new_chat_members = len(call.message.new_chat_members)

    ChatMemberMember.status = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, user_id=call.from_user.id)
    ChatMemberUpdated.new_chat_member = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, user_id=call.from_user.id)
    if ChatMemberUpdated.new_chat_member in ChatMemberMember.status and user_id in to_id:
        await bot.restrict_chat_member(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, user_id=call.from_user.id, permissions=types.ChatPermissions(can_send_messages=True, can_send_media_messages=True, can_send_other_messages=True, can_add_web_page_previews=True, can_send_polls=True, can_pin_messages=True, can_invite_users=True, can_change_info=True, until_date=None))
        if db.user_exists(user_id, chat_id):
            db.add_to_db(call.from_user.id, chat_id, name, username, new_chat_members)

    elif user_id in to_id:
        await call.answer(text="Вы пригласили, меньше 40 или ни кого, не пригласили.", show_alert=True)

    else:
        await call.answer(text="Эта ссылка адресована другому пользователю", show_alert=True)
```

фото с ошибкой.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Фото с ошибкой": одна скобка не закрыта на строке выше, красное подчеркивание на той строке как бы намекает на это. См.: [Вроде всё правильно, а выдаёт, что неправильный синтаксис](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1066612/1365)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете добавить автоматическую проверку на кол-во приглашенных пользователей.

```
def check_new_users(self, user_id):
     with self.connection:
          res = self.cursor.execute("SELECT new_chat_members FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,))
          for row in res.fetchall():
               rslt = row[0]
          if rslt >= 20:
               return True
          else:
               return False
```

Этот метод будет подключаться к БД и проверять кол-во приглашенных пользователей по `user_id` и возвращать `True` если значение равно или больше 20, в противном случае результатом выполнения станет `False`.

Теперь используя этот метод в `main`

```
db.check_new_users(user_id)
```

На основе полученных данных вы сможете снять ограничения. К примеру, используя:

```
if db.check_new_users(user_id):
     #тут снимите ограничения с пользователя
```

Comment: ругается на эту строку for row in res.fetchall():   ошибка SyntaxError: invalid syntax и row почему то, не чёрный.
В вопрос вставил фото, с ошибкой

Comment: @Miki не закрыта одна скобка  в строке `res = self.cursor.execute(...`

Comment: @insolor исправил ответ. Спасибо

Comment: Пишет ошибку     if db.check_new_users(user_id):
AttributeError: 'SQLither' object has no attribute 'check_new_users'

Comment: @Miki метод `check_new_users` нужно добавить в код БД, а не в основной файл.

Comment: Подскажите, куда прописать, у меня, все, в одном файле.

Comment: Туда же, где вы прописывали функции из предыдущего вопроса.

Comment: Благодарю, всё сделал, всё заработало, поставил, изменил 20 на 2, написал текст, ограничения установились, как только добавил 2, ограничения снялись. Спасибо.

Comment: Всегда рад помочь

Comment: У меня вопросик, можно ли, сделать так, чтобы начальная цифра была 0 или None, хочу подключить к каналу. Например, если подписался, на канал, но не пригласил контакты, значит, не сможет, опубликовать. Если пригласил 20, значит колонка new_chat_members изменится.


'    def add_user(self, user_id, chat_id, name, username, new_chat_members):
            with self.connection:
                return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' (user_id, chat_id, name, username, new_chat_members) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)", (user_id, chat_id, name, username, new_chat_members))'

Comment: Поставьте стандартное значение в БД на 0. Посмотрите как это сделать "set default value sql"

Comment: Верно же, я сделал, думаю ДА `new_chat_members` INTEGER DEFAULT 0

Comment: Подскажите, выставил цифру 2, но при добавление, всего 1 контакта, ограничения снимаются, подскажите, как прописать, чтобы, работало правильно.